# connect to redshift from AWS EMR using pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-iam

I am trying to connect to redshift from EMR cluster using pyspark to perform operations like create a table, insert data and read data from the table.Is it possible to create a connection in spark using AWS IAM roles instead of passing credentials ?